# How to load a text file?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I want to load a file `collection1.txt`. So I wrote:

```
function [output] = calculate_tfidf('E:\backup\Media\collection1.txt')
end
```

But when I run the program to see if file has been loaded I  get the message  below:

> Error: File: `calculate_tfidf.m` Line: 2 Column: 36
>   Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please take a basic tutorial or read the documentation to learn how to define  functions. You cannot just type random text and expect it to work. Did you type your exact question title in Google? Because that gives many working solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at `dlmread`?

Answer (score 0):

So you were defining a function, but you need to call that function,
In a modern version of Matlab you could code this something more like this:

```
 Tfidf=calculate_tfidf('E:\backup\Media\collection1.txt')
```

Now below that in the same file, define the actual function

```
 function output= calculate_tfidf(filename)
 % now put your function cde in here
 % Eg...

 data = extractFileText(filename);
 text = split(data,newline);
 output = tokenizedDocument(text);

 end
```